# Loop through keys inside multi dimensional object

Tags: javascript

I have an object with multiple objects, and need to create a loop for each key within each object.

I need the console to log something like this.

```
Iron
TIBC
carbon dioxide
Sodium
etc...
```

This is what I have tried so far

```js
(function() {
  var blood = {
    "blood": {
      "one": {
        "iron": "Iron",
        "tibc": "TIBC",

      },
      "two": {
        "cd": "Carbon Dioxide",
        "sodium": "Sodium",
        "potassium": "Potassium",
        "chloride": "Chloride",
      },
      "three": {
        "cholesterol": "Cholesterol",
        "dhdl": "Direct HDL",
      },
      "four": {
        "rigg": "Rubella IgG",
        "hbsag": "HBsAg",
        "ahiv": "Anti-HIV 1+2",
        "estrdiol": "Estradiol",
        "fsh": "FSH",
      }
    }
  }

  for (var key in blood) {
    if (blood.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var newKey = blood[key]

      for (var key in newKey) {
        if (newKey.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          //do stuff
          console.log(newKey[key])
        }
      }

    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Your code re-uses "key" inside the outer loop. It would work better (in newer JavaScript environments) if you declared the variables with `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: Your inner loop is overwriting the variable `key` try changing it to a different name

Comment: You're also not executing your IIFE (place `()` at the very end!)

Comment: @brenjt It never reuses the variable in that loop, so it shouldn't cause a failure, but I agree it's bad form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

You are looping through the keys with a for loop, so by recursively calling the same for loop and showing the output only if the `value` of the object is a string, we can get the desired output, if its type is `object` then call the function again.

```js
var blood = {
  "blood": {
    "one": {
      "iron": "Iron",
      "tibc": "TIBC",

    },
    "two": {
      "cd": "Carbon Dioxide",
      "sodium": "Sodium",
      "potassium": "Potassium",
      "chloride": "Chloride",
    },
    "three": {
      "cholesterol": "Cholesterol",
      "dhdl": "Direct HDL",
    },
    "four": {
      "rigg": "Rubella IgG",
      "hbsag": "HBsAg",
      "ahiv": "Anti-HIV 1+2",
      "estrdiol": "Estradiol",
      "fsh": "FSH",
    }
  }
}

function keyGetter(data){
  for(key in data){
    if(typeof data[key] === typeof ""){
      console.log(data[key]);
    }else{
      keyGetter(data[key]);
    }
  }
}
keyGetter(blood);
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem was and how you fixed it. Also, click the Tidy button in the snippet.

Comment: Ok i see what I was missing. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user2168066 can you check my answer again, I applied recursion and got the keys alone, this is a bit more confusing  but lesser coding and a better thing to use!

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I made the corrections, sorry usually I edit my answer after I post it!

Answer (score 1):

Thats what Object.values is for:

```
 const result = Object.values( blood.blood ).map(
   obj => Object.values(obj).join("\n")
 ).join("\n");

 console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the values into an array with the following:

```
let allTypes = [];

Object.values(blood.blood).forEach(v => {
  // we are iterating over "one"..."four"
  allTypes.push(...Object.values(v));
});

console.log(allTypes);
```

Will output `["Iron", "TIBC", "Carbon Dioxide", "Sodium", "Potassium", "Chloride", "Cholesterol", "Direct HDL", "Rubella IgG", "HBsAg", "Anti-HIV 1+2", "Estradiol", "FSH"]`.

https://jsbin.com/kodolok/edit?js,console

[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) is really useful when iterating over objects that are basically associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I made a recursive function that may help you!

```js
var blood = {
        "blood": {
            "one": {
                "iron": "Iron",
                "tibc": "TIBC",

            },
            "two": {
                "cd": "Carbon Dioxide",
                "sodium": "Sodium",
                "potassium": "Potassium",
                "chloride": "Chloride",
            },
            "three": {
                "cholesterol": "Cholesterol",
                "dhdl": "Direct HDL",
            },
            "four": {
                "rigg": "Rubella IgG",
                "hbsag": "HBsAg",
                "ahiv": "Anti-HIV 1+2",
                "estrdiol": "Estradiol",
                "fsh": "FSH",
            }
        }
}

loopThrough(blood)

function loopThrough(obj){
   if(typeof obj == "object"){
     for(var i in obj){
       loopThrough(obj[i]);
     }
   }else{
     console.log(obj)
   }
  
}
```